# Writing a loud failing scanf: which is the type signature?

Tags: c, input, types, scanf

I decided to write a variation of the `scan` C function that instead of returning an `int` stating success or failure would print an error message and abort the program on error.

```
void aborting_scanf(const char *format, ???) {  
  if (scanf(format, &var) != 1)
    puts("Invalid input");
    exit(1);
}
```

The problem is what to write instead of the `???`, in [the man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf), the type signature is:

```
int scanf(const char *format, ...)
```

But then how can I name the target variable?

In theory I could write a version for each type by hand but it would incredibly repetitive so I am looking for a more general solution to avoid code duplication.

Comment: Look for a tutorial on C varargs. Note that this kind of error "handling" isn't actually very smart, so I hope you don't plan to use this in production.

Comment: The BIG probleme of your approach is 'how can you say for sure that a scanf fail ?'.
I mean, okay, if scan return -1, it's an error, but if scanf return 1 and you want to retrieve 2 variable with scanf, is it a failure for you ? Either you will have to parse format, or you will have to pass the exepected return of scanf. Or you can ignore this case.

Comment: @Tom's I will use it for one variable at a time so `!= 1` represents failure

Answer (score 4):

You need to use [variable arguments](http://linux.die.net/man/3/stdarg) for this along with `vscanf`:

```
void aborting_scanf(const char *format, ...) {  
  va_list ap;

  va_start(ap, format);
  if (vscanf(format, ap) != 1) {
    puts("Invalid input");
    exit(1);
  }
  va_end(ap);
}
```

The `...` argument tells the compiler that the remaining arguments are of varying types and numbers and can be anything.  The variable of type `va_list` allows you to access these values, and the `vscanf` function can read this directly.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` uses a *variable argument list* as indicated by the `...` parameter. You manipulate these with the functions in `stdarg.h`. This format is not suitable to give a full introduction into variable argument lists, read a tutorial/book of choice about it.